# Azure Blob Storage: Mocking CloudBlobContainer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to unittest a class which uploads files to Azure Blob Storage. The uploading method takes `CloudBlobContainer` as input. When calling `_storageContainer.Object.GetBlockBlobReference()`, a System.NullReferenceException is thrown. Can anyone help me mocking this?

Unittest code:

```
[TestClass()]
public class BlobStorageServiceUploadUnitTest
{
    private static BlobStorageService _service;
    private static Mock<CloudBlobContainer> _storageContainer;
    private static List<FileType> _extensions;
    private static int _maxSize;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Setup_Service(TestContext context)
    {
        _extensions = new List<FileType> { FileType.Image };
        _maxSize = 2048;

        _storageContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>();

        _service = new BlobStorageService(new Mock<BEntitiesContainer>().Object, _storageContainer.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void When_FileIsDeleted()
    {
        var file = CreateMockFile("test.jpg", 500000);
        var blob = _storageContainer.Object.GetBlockBlobReference("deleteTest.jpg");
        blob.UploadFromStream(file.Object.InputStream);

        _service.DeleteFromStorage("deleteTest.jpg");

        var blobs = _storageContainer.Object.ListBlobs();
        Assert.AreEqual(0, blobs.Count());
    }


    public Mock<HttpPostedFileBase> CreateMockFile(string fileName, int sizeInBytes)
    {
        var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        file.Setup(pf => pf.InputStream).Returns(stream);
        file.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns(fileName);
        file.Setup(f => f.ContentLength).Returns(sizeInBytes);

        return file;
    }
}
```

Tested class:

```
public class BlobStorageService : BaseRepository<User>
{
    private CloudBlobContainer _storageContainer;

    public BlobStorageService(BEntitiesContainer context, CloudBlobContainer storageContainer) : base(context)
    {
        Context = context;
        _storageContainer = storageContainer;
    }

    public void DeleteFromStorage(string fileName)
    {
        _storageContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName).DeleteIfExists();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.From [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/318) that we know that GetBlockBlobReference is supported from [Azure Storage SDK 8.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/8.0.0). If  it is not latest version in you case, please have a try to update to the latest version. 2.If it is possible, plesae share the whole code(about storage container unitest ) of the project. 3. We also can use the [Azure storage emulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator) for test and it is free for us debugging and test. Then no need to use moq.

Comment: I will reply in the order of questions: 1. I've seen that one but I fail to see how that will lead to a working implementation for me. 2. This is the whole code. 3. When I start using the Emulator, my test is not a unittest anymore but becomes an integrationtest (my teacher is very strict upon the distinction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock CloudBlobClient with AutoFac and AutoMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876042/mock-cloudblobclient-with-autofac-and-automock)

Answer (score 1):

Only one thing you can do is to move CloudBlobContainer operation to the separate service with the abstract implementation. In this case you will be able to mock the service and not to touch the Azure classes at all.

For example:

```
public interface IAzureServiceWrapper
{
    CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(CloudBlobContainer storageContainer, string fileName);
}

public class AzureServiceWrapper : IAzureServiceWrapper
{
    public CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(CloudBlobContainer storageContainer, string fileName)
    {
         storageContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName).DeleteIfExists();
    }
}
```

In this case it will be very easy to mock the AzureServiceWrapper and this solution will solve all the problems with Azure classes using in unit tests. You just need to use AzureServiceWrapper in BlobStorageService instead of CloudBlobContainer.