# How can I implement mock(s) for this unit test?

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I need to write a unit test for the following method:

```
private async Task<bool> CreateFileAsync(string fileContent, string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
{
  CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = await GetCloudStorageAccount(connectionString);
  CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  CloudBlobContainer containerRef = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
  CloudBlockBlob blobRef = containerRef.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
  await blobRef.UploadTextAsync(fileContent);

  return true;
}
```

I need to write an xUnit unit test which will throw an `HttpException` when `blobRef.UploadTextAsync(fileContent)` is called.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudBlockBlob : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.ICloudBlob
```

But `CloudStorageAccount` doesn't implement an interface so it does not appear that I can mock it.

Here's some sample unit test code based on what I understand about mocking and pieced together for this particular scenario:

```
var cloudBlockBlobMock = new Mock<ICloudBlob>();
cloudBlockBlobMock
    .Setup(cbb => cbb.UploadTextAsync("test"))
    .Throws<HttpException>();
var fileUploader = new FileUploader(cloudBlockBlobMock);
fileUploader.CreateFileAsync("test");
```

Is `CreateFileAsync()` unit-testable?

Is it possible/valid to mock a child object without mocking its parent object?

Comment: The shown code snippet is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that would make mocking difficult.

Comment: What is `GetCloudStorageAccount`? [edit] the question with a [mcve] to get better suggestions about your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock CloudBlobClient with AutoFac and AutoMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876042/mock-cloudblobclient-with-autofac-and-automock)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft took another approach when it came to making the libs unit testable. Instead of implementing interfaces, the types have most methods virtual. For example, the [`CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.createcloudblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) method is virtual. [You can mock those in Moq.](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Or you could use a wrapper that wraps the implementation in an interface and use that. See e.g. [Microsoft/Azure.Data.Wrappers](https://github.com/Microsoft/Azure.Data.Wrappers) or [pvredeveld/Azure.Storage.Wrappers](https://github.com/pvredeveld/Azure.Storage.Wrappers). These will provide an interface you can mock but you have to change your existing codebase to use them.

Comment: I found several GitHub issues that make it clear that that making the methods virtual is really a design choice related to mocking. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/5514 https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/318

Comment: Looks like there is even a label [mocking-enhancement](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/labels/mocking-enhancement), bug it is used only on two older issues, which both suggest to create interfaces for the clients.

Comment: Another related one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the below code snippet

```
Mock<CloudStorageAccount> obj = new Mock<CloudStorageAccount>();
```

and then you can setup any function or property